# Thunderbird + S/Mime, Ecnryption Selection?

Tags: email, thunderbird, encryption

As can be seen [here](http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/AES-support-in-S-MIME-encrypted-mails-td273981.html) and [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/thunderbird_how_to_select_ciper_and_hash_for_s_mime), Thunderbird does not offer an option to select a more modern encryption algorithm than 3DES when sending S/MIME encrypted mail.

Is there any way to change this by using a plugin, modifying a config file, etc? Or is there any way to use Enigmail for S/MIME mails?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, this is not possible in Thunderbird. A ticket for this is opened in 2003 and has not been resolved as of yet. However, patches with options for SHA-2 signing and AES encryption have been posted already. Please refer to [bug #222179](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=222179) for more information.

Comment: That bug is a 17-year tale of woe :/  It seems the change to silently use AES instead of silently use 3-DES kicked in for TB about a year ago (NSS 3.42).